# Laravel eloquent add string to result.

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I use eloquent to retrieve data from a `posts` table. Here is a simplified example:

```
$posts = Post::with(
    array('user'=>function($query){
        $query->select('id','username');
    }))
    ->with('category')
    ->with('images')
    ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
    ->paginate(25);
```

The result for `images` looks like this:

```
"images": [
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "user_id": 1,
                    "post_id": 104,
                    "file": "cb2a81314c006425e7d7fb1fcb4ebd66c2ea5a75.jpg",
                    "width": 1050,
                    "height": 1204,
                    "created_at": "2018-09-23 15:53:24",
                    "updated_at": "2018-09-23 15:53:24"
                }
            ]
```

Is there a way, I can add a string, respectively a link to the filename so that it looks like this: `https://example.com/uploads/cb2a81314c006425e7d7fb1fcb4ebd66c2ea5a75.jpg`

I haven't found a way to do this by myself and would be happy if someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`$appends`](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json):

```php
class Image extends Model {
    protected $appends = ['url'];

    public function getUrlAttribute() {
        return 'https://example.com/uploads/'.$this->file;
    }
}
```